# How to use Python with Gazebo

Tags: python

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I just installed Gazebo on Ubuntu. I want to set up a basic simulation where I can control robots as well as environment via Python. Via Google I found information on libgazebo.a, however from this I do not understand where to find the python files to include or what to install to get them.

I would be very happy if someone can help me!
Thanks
Timo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/924/how-to-use-python-with-gazebo/) by [timo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/162/timo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is no python interface to Gazebo. You'll have to write c++ plugins, or use ROS or Player.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As of Feb. 2014 it seems there is an interface available called [pygazebo](https://github.com/jpieper/pygazebo).

---

Originally posted by [edgimar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/793/edgimar/) with karma: 11 on 2014-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tytteboevsen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1216/tytteboevsen/) on 2015-05-18**:
Anybody got pygazebo working. Can't get it to work.

**Comment by [ArpanHalder](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4824/arpanhalder/) on 2018-03-24**:
is it possible make pygazebo subscribe a topic in gazebo and publish it using rospy in ROS?